# Clang-Format: how to get one-line case statements in a switch statement

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is it possible to obtain `switch` statements formatted as:

```
switch (index) {
  case 0: /* statement */ break;
  case 1: /* statement */ break;
  default: break;
}
```

with Clang-Format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to set `AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine` to `true`. You can experiment in real-time with your `.clang-format` configuration on [this great website: "clang-format-configurator"](http://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/).

[image: Clang-format configurator screenshot]

Comment: But is there a way to get it to not have an opinion? Whether you set that option to true or not, it comes to its own conclusion about what goes on one line. I want options to preserve the existing formatting.