# How to get single line aligned case statements in a switch, using clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I would like [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) to format like:

```
switch (x)
{
case long_name: return 1;
case sn:        return 2;
}
```

The `AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine` option gets them on the same line, 
but I have not found a way to get the statements **aligned**.

Comment: This seems to be more of a problem with your IDE.

Which one are you using?

Comment: @U.W. [`clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) is an external tool for formatting code, I don't think this has anything to do with a specific IDE.

Comment: This is a duplicate. The original question has the answer you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565261, `AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true`.

Comment: @lmat That answer does not address how to get the statements aligned.

Comment: I see. I've retracted my "Close" vote.

Comment: Any update on this?
This is such a great idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of right now, it's not possible to do what you're asking using ClangFormat.

The official explanation as to why that is:

> Each additional style option adds costs to the clang-format project.
>   Some of these costs affect the clang-format development itself, as we
>   need to make sure that any given combination of options work and that
>   new features don’t break any of the existing options in any way. There
>   are also costs for end users as options become less discoverable and
>   people have to think about and make a decision on options they don’t
>   really care about.
>
> The goal of the clang-format project is more on the side of supporting
>   a limited set of styles really well as opposed to supporting every
>   single style used by a codebase somewhere in the wild. [...]

The only way you may be able to do something like that would be to:

1. Suggest the style option to the developers;
2. Wait until the desired style option gets added;
3. Use an alternative to ClangFormat which is capable of aligning the statements.

*Sources:*

1. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configurable-format-style-options
2. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#adding-additional-style-options

Answer (score -2):

Add to .clang-format file.

AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true

Comment: this does not answer the question